# TextBlock1.Background = "myBrush" & 1 is not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net

xaml codes are here;

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Width="100" Height="20" Background="Blue"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

vb.net codes are here;

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim myBrush1 As New SolidColorBrush(CType(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF0000"), Color))
    TextBlock1.Background = myBrush1
End Sub
End Class
```

The codes above are okey.

My question is here;

I want to use

```
TextBlock1.Background = "myBrush" & 1
```

instead of

```
TextBlock1.Background = myBrush1
```

**TextBlock1.Background = "myBrush" & 1** is not working.

So, how can I make **TextBlock1.Background = "myBrush" & 1** is working?

Comment: Why?  Are you planning on a "2"?

Comment: @dbasnett Yes, I have 500 colors from myBrush1 to myBrush500.

Comment: How about adding all of the colors to a list and then access the color you want by index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a string as a variable name in that way.

What you can do instead is have some kind of collection which associates an object (in this case a Brush) with a string. A [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) will serve this purpose well here.

You could have something like:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private myBrushes As New Dictionary(Of String, Brush)

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim myBrush1 As New SolidColorBrush(DirectCast(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF0000"), Color))
        myBrushes.Add("myBrush1", myBrush1)

        TextBlock1.Background = myBrushes("myBrush" & "1")

    End Sub

End Class
```

The value of `myBrushes("myBrush1")` is the SolidColorBrush `myBrush1`. You can add as many brushes as you want to the dictionary.

Comment: @MichaelScofield - what Andrew has shown you is as good of answer as you are going to get.  His first statement is spot on.